# How to tell if variable is empty?

Tags: php

```
<?php
echo $Variable;
?>

**//  I would like to check if the variable is empty, using but if() statements but more secure     than...**
  if($var == "")
```

is it possible to check if variable is empty more secure than this ?

Comment: What security problem are you worried about?

Comment: Wellthat people might hack through it trying to be secure as I can.

Comment: possible duplicate of [if($val) vs. if($val != "") vs. if(!empty($val)) -- which one?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7384913/ifval-vs-ifval-vs-ifemptyval-which-one)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[empty()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php)

Answer (score 6):

```
if(!isset($var) || $var == "")
{
    //$var is empty.
}
```

^ Thats what I use, it also covers if you haven't 'initialised' it yet.

*edit - to reflect comments

Comment: I would flip the `isset()` with the empty string check, that way if the variable isn't set, you don't get an error.  also, I would add `trim()` around `$var` to strip any whitespace

Answer (score 2):

If (!isset($var) || empty($var))

Answer (score 1):

Try this isset as a function

```
isset($variable)
```

Answer (score 1):

using [isset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)