# if($val) vs. if($val != "") vs. if(!empty($val)) -- which one?

Tags: php, if-statement

I see a lot of people using a variety of different methods to check whether of a variable is empty, there really seems to be no consensus. I've heard that `if($foo)` is exactly the same as `if(!empty($foo))` or `if($foo != "")`. **Is this true?**

I realize it's a really simple question, but I'd really like to know. Are there any differences? Which method should I use?

Comment: I propose that the question be reopened: the inclusion of the `if($foo != "")` alternative *certainly does* make it different than the simple "if vs empty" question -- see my answer for proof.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

### Difference between bare test and comparison to empty string

`if($foo != "")` is equivalent to `if($foo)` *most of the time, but not always*.

To see where the differences are, consider the [comparison operator behavior](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) along with the [conversion to string rules](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.casting) for the first case, and the [conversion to boolean rules](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting) for the second case.

What I found out is that:

- if `$foo === array()`, the `if($foo != "")` test will succeed (arrays are "greater than" strings), but the `if($foo)` test will fail (empty arrays convert to boolean `false`)
- if `$foo === "0"` (a string), the `if($foo != "")` test will again succeed (obviously), but the `if($foo)` test will fail (the string `"0"` converts to boolean `false`)
- if `$foo` is a SimpleXML object created from an empty tag, the `if($foo != "")` test will again succeed (objects are "greater than" strings), but the `if($foo)` test will fail (such objects convert to boolean `false`)

**[See the differences in action](http://www.ideone.com/Bvlmu)**.

### The better way to test

The **preferred method to test** is `if(!empty($foo))`, which is *not* exactly equal to the above in that:

1. It does not suffer from the inconsistencies of `if($foo != "")` (which IMHO is simply horrible).
2. It will not generate an `E_NOTICE` if `$foo` is not present in the current scope, which is its main advantage over `if($foo)`.

There's a caveat here though: if `$foo === '0'` (a string of length 1) then `empty($foo)` will return `true`, which usually is (but may not *always* be) what you want. This is also the case with `if($foo)` though.

### Sometimes you need to test with the identical operator

Finally, an exception to the above must be made when there is a specific type of value you want to test for. As an example, `strpos` might return `0` and also might return `false`. Both of these values will fail the `if(strpos(...))` test, but they have totally different meanings. In these cases, a test with the [identical operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) is in order: `if(strpos() === false)`.

Comment: Thanks :). So many great answers, but I'll accept yours when the timer drops for the most thorough explanation.

Comment: @Pixelatron: Thank you. Unfortunately this question was closed, but I hope it will be reopened because its depth is certainly greater than "if vs empty".

Comment: As of php 5.5 `empty()` can now be used on arbitrary expressions. See: http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.new-features.php#migration55.new-features.empty. So `echo empty(array());` will output `1`

Comment: @fyrye I've updated the answer by simply deleting that passage. Thank you for the heads up!

Answer (score 5):

No it's not always true. When you do `if($foo)` PHP casts the variable to Boolean. An empty string, a Zero integer or an empty array will then be `false`. Sometimes this can be an issue.

You should always try to use the most specific comparison as possible, if you're expecting a string which could be empty use `if($foo==='')` (note the three equal signs). If you're expecting either (boolean) false or a resource (from a DB query for instance) use `if($foo===false){...} else {...}`

Answer (score 0):

You may read the [documentation about casting to boolean](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting) to find the answer to this question. There's a list in there with which values are converted to `true` and `false`, respectively.

Note that [empty](http://php.net/empty) also checks if the variable is set, which regular comparison does not. An unset variable will trigger an error of type E_NOTICE during comparison, but not when using empty. You can work around this using the [isset](http://php.net/isset) call before your comparison, like this:

```
if(isset($foo) && $foo != '')
```

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks for the link to the documentation, now I actually have an understanding of how `if()` works. I guess I'll just use `if(!empty($foo))` in the instances when I need it, so as to not generate an E_NOTICE

Answer (score 0):

`if()` "converts" the statement given to a bool, so taking a look at the [documentation for boolean](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php) seems to be what you're looking for. in general:

- empty strings (`""`), empty arrays (`array()`), zero (`0`) and boolean false (`false`) are treated as `false`
- everything else (`"foo"`, `1`, `array('foo')`, `true`, ...) is treated as `true`

**EDIT :**
for more information, you could also check the [type comparison tables](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php).

Answer (score 0):

empty($foo) should return true in all of these cases: 0,"", NULL.

For a more complete list check this page: http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not equal. When variable is not defined, expression without `empty` will generate  notice about non-defined variable.