# Foreach while loop php issue

Tags: php, while-loop

I'm trying to display only the names that are not empty from this array on a new line for each. Currently, using this, it is only displaying "$playerName1"'s name 10 times. I'm trying to figure out why it's not actually looping through all 10 playerName's. It seems to only be checking $playerName1.

```
$z = array($playerName1, $playerName2, $playerName3, $playerName4, $playerName5, $playerName6, $playerName7, $playerName8, $playerName9, $playerName10);
$zCounter = 1;
foreach ($z as $allNames) {
  while ($allNames != "" && $zCounter < 11) {
    echo $allNames . "<br>";
    $zCounter++;
  }
}
```

Comment: Get rid of the inner `while` loop.

Comment: On an issue unrelated to the question, but showing up in your code, [consider using `!empty($allNames)`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7384913/ifval-vs-ifval-vs-ifemptyval-which-one).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you want to output each `name` 10 times, remove the `while` loop. You can still check to make sure the name is not empty by using `!=''` or `empty()`

```
<?php
$z = array($playerName1, $playerName2, $playerName3, $playerName4, $playerName5, $playerName6, $playerName7, $playerName8, $playerName9, $playerName10);
foreach($z as $name){
    if(!empty($name)){
        echo $name.'<br>';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is that you are going through the inner `while` loop for only the first player name.  The outer `foreach` loop should be plenty:

```
foreach ($z as $playerName) {
  if ("" !== $playerName) {
    echo $playerName . "<br />";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to reset the $zCounter after each while loop

```
foreach ($z as $allNames) {
  while ($allNames != "" && $zCounter < 11) {
    echo $allNames . "<br>";
    $zCounter++;
  }
  $zCounter = 0;
}
```

otherwise after the first while loop finishes, $zCounter will always be 11

Comment: Why the downvote this perfectly fixes his problem. He didnt say anything about not wanting them each displayed 10 times.