# Can you tell me what's wrong with this PHP form?

Tags: php, html, forms

I'm trying to make a simple website in which I ask the user for their name and DOB in order to output "Hello (name) you are (age) years old and you will graduate in (Graduation Date). I feel like my code is right but when i submit the form it leads me to a blank page.

My code:
**HTML**

```
<body>
  <center>
    <form action="aform.php" method="post">
      Name:<input type="text" name="name" />
      <br />
      Date of Birth:
      <input type="text" size="4" placeholder="mm" name="month" /> 
      <input type="text" size="4" placeholder="dd" name="day" />
      <input type="text" size="6" placeholder="yyyy" name="year" />
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
      <br />
    </form>
  </center>
</body>
```

PHP:

```
<?php

if($_POST["submit"]){

    $name = $_POST["name"];
    $day = $_POST["day"];
    $month = $_POST["month"];
    $year = $_POST["year"];
    $datedisplay = date("yyyy");
    $birth = array($day,$month,$year);

    if($name = $year = $month = $day = ""){
        echo "You must fill out everything!";
    } else if($year = $month = $day > 0) {
        $yourage = 2014 - $year;
        $gradyear = $year + 22;
        $graddate = "6/TBA/$gradyear"; 
        echo "Hello" . $name . ", you are" . $yourage . "years old and you will graduate from college in" . $graddate ; 
    }   
}
?>
```

Sorry if I presented this wrong I'm new to this website.

Comment: = is the assignment operator, you can't compare variables values with it. Use == instead.
Take a look to this page : http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your tests are wrong. Here is a corrected code:

```
<?php

if($_POST["submit"]) {

    $name = $_POST["name"];
    $day = $_POST["day"];
    $month = $_POST["month"];
    $year = $_POST["year"];
    $datedisplay = date("yyyy");
    $birth = array($day,$month,$year);

    if(empty($name) || empty($year) || empty($month) || empty($day)) {
        echo "You must fill out everything!";
    } else if($year > 0 && $month > 0 && $day > 0) {
        $yourage = 2014 - $year;
        $gradyear = $year + 22;
        $graddate = "6/TBA/$gradyear"; 
        echo "Hello" . $name . ", you are" . $yourage . "years old and you will graduate from college in" . $graddate ; 
    }   
}
?>
```

Comment: Use empty() function instead of == "" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7384913/ifval-vs-ifval-vs-ifemptyval-which-one

Comment: No problem @Apolo. == "" works too but empty() is a little more classy and efficient :)

Comment: I won't be able to test it until wednesday but thank you guys!

Answer (score 0):

I think

```
if($name = $year = $month = $day = ""){
    echo "You must fill out everything!";
}
```

that is not working very well. You should check every variable with **empty** or **isset**.
With one **=** you give the variable a value in your case nothing.

```
if(!empty($name) && !empty($year) && !empty($month)) {
```

Answer (score 0):

1) you need to use == in ifs ... a single = works differently
( this way, you just try to check, if you can assign the value of $year to $name )

```
if($name = $year = $month = $day = "")
```

2) you need to rewrite that if

```
if( ( strlen( $name ) == 0 ) && ( strlen( $year ) == 0 ) .....
```

3) yo need to rewrite your elseif stuff as well

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
<?php

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){

$name = $_POST["name"];
$day = $_POST["day"];
$month = $_POST["month"];
$year = $_POST["year"];
$datedisplay = date("yyyy");
$birth = array($day,$month,$year);

    if($name == "" || $year == "" || $month == "" || $day == ""){
    echo "You must fill out everything!";
    }

    else if($year > 0 && $month > 0 && $day > 0){
    $yourage = 2014 - $year;
    $gradyear = $year + 22;
    $graddate = "6/TBA/$gradyear"; 
    echo "Hello" . $name . ", you are" . $yourage . "years old and you will graduate from college in" . $graddate ; 
    }

}
?>
```

if this does not work, edit your question and add the HTML form code that you have written

Comment: You think `if($name = $year = $month = $day = "")` is correct?

Comment: What is this ..?
if($name = $year = $month = $day = ""){
    echo "You must fill out everything!";
    }

Comment: I think for reusability purpose you should explain what you made here.

Comment: Thanks @ioums, silly of me. I didnt check the usability of the rest of the code from the question.

Comment: Well I would remove my downvote, but I can't (what a ridiculous rule; see here http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/150002) unless you make another edit.

Comment: Well thats okay @ioums, i should remember my mistakes and make sure i dont repeat them. :)

Answer (score -1):

do not use assign operator instead of compression operator. in php

```
if($name = $year = $month = $day = ""){

}   
else if($year = $month = $day > 0){}
```