# PHP - Don't display empty database field remove div/image

Tags: php, html

How would I make it so for example, if there isn't a mobile number for an entry the mobile icon will not show up maybe removing the div?

```
if ($numrows > 0){
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
        echo "<div class='result-container'>

            <div class='titlebox'>
            <h2>" . $row['name'] . "</h2>
            <p><strong>" . $row['services'] . "</strong></p>
                <div class='iconbox'>
                    <a href='" . $row['tel'] . "'><img src='img/icons/phone.png' ></a>
                    <a href='" . $row['mob'] . "'><img src='img/icons/mobile.png' ></a>
                    <a href='mailto:" . $row['email'] . "'><img src='img/icons/email.png' ></a>
                    <a href='" . $row['web_url'] . "'><img src='img/icons/web.png' ></a>
                 </div>
            </div>

        </div>";
                    }
                }
            }
            else
                echo "<h3>No results found </h3>";

            mysql_close(); ?>
```

Comment: before echo add if condition `if($row['mob']) !==''){your div code}`

Comment: the snippet you've pasted contains an "if" so I am sure you know how to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could check whether it is `empty()` or not:

```
" . ((empty($row['mob'])) ? '' : "<a href='" . $row['mob'] . "'><img src='img/icons/mobile.png' ></a>") . "
```

[Read here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7384953/601299) why you might want to choose `empty()` over alternative methods like `!=`.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be working I have placed it inside my echo but it seems to break the code.

Comment: I've tested and it works without error for me. I've tweaked it slightly - try now? That should be on the line one its own